# How to insert multiple values with subquery using SQLAlchemy Core?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy Core (not ORM), I'm trying to INSERT multiple rows using subqueries in the values. For MySQL, the actual SQL would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO widgets (name, type) VALUES
('Melon', (SELECT type FROM widgetTypes WHERE type='Squidgy')),
('Durian', (SELECT type FROM widgetTypes WHERE type='Spiky'))
```

But I only seem to be able to use subqueries when using the [`values()`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert.values) method on an [`insert()`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.insert) clause which only allows me to do one insert at a time. I'd like to insert multiple values at once by passing them all to the `Connection`'s [`execute()`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connectable.execute) method as a list of bind parameters, but this doesn't seem to be supported.

Is it possible to do what I want in a single call to `execute()`?

Here's a self contained demonstration. Note this uses the sqlite engine which [doesn't support multiple inserts in the same way as MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1609637/445073), but the SQLAlchemy code still fails in the same way as the real MySQL app.

```
from sqlalchemy import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Construct database
    metadata = MetaData()
    widgetTypes = Table('widgetTypes', metadata,
        Column('id', INTEGER(), primary_key=True),
        Column('type', VARCHAR(), nullable=False),
    )
    widgets = Table('widgets', metadata,
        Column('id', INTEGER(), primary_key=True),
        Column('name', VARCHAR(), nullable=False),
        Column('type', INTEGER(), nullable=False),
        ForeignKeyConstraint(['type'], ['widgetTypes.id']),
    )
    engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
    metadata.create_all(engine)

    # Connect and populate db for testing
    conn = engine.connect()
    conn.execute(widgetTypes.insert(), [
        {'type': 'Spiky'},
        {'type': 'Squidgy'},
    ])

    # Some select queries for later use.
    select_squidgy_id = select([widgetTypes.c.id]).where(
        widgetTypes.c['type']=='Squidgy'
    ).limit(1)
    select_spiky_id = select([widgetTypes.c.id]).where(
        widgetTypes.c['type']=='Squidgy'
    ).limit(1)

    # One at a time works via values()
    conn.execute(widgets.insert().values(
        {'name': 'Tomato', 'type': select_squidgy_id},
    ))

    # And multiple values work if we avoid subqueries
    conn.execute(
        widgets.insert(),
        {'name': 'Melon',  'type': 2},
        {'name': 'Durian', 'type': 1},
    )

    # Check above inserts did actually work
    print conn.execute(widgets.select()).fetchall()

    # But attempting to insert many at once with subqueries does not work.
    conn.execute(
        widgets.insert(),
        {'name': 'Raspberry', 'type': select_squidgy_id},
        {'name': 'Lychee',    'type': select_spiky_id},
    )
```

Run it and it dies on the last `execute()` call with:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (InterfaceError) Error binding
>   parameter 1 - probably unsupported type. u'INSERT INTO widgets (name,
>   type) VALUES (?, ?)' (('Raspberry', <sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select
>   at 0x19f14d0; Select object>), ('Lychee',
>   <sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select at 0x19f1a50; Select object>))

Comment: I have a gut feeling that you're doing it wrong - currently you want to execute a subquery for every single record. And because you are using SQLAlchemy Core, it means that all the SQL will be executed exactly as you supply it.

Comment: @plaes yep that's exactly what I want to do (execute a subquery for every single record), you'll just have to trust me that it makes more sense in the real application `:)`. But the problem is that SQLAlchemy **isn't** executing exactly what I supply, and is refusing to process the `Select` expression `:(`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of providing subselect statement as parameter value, you have to embed it into INSERT statement:

```
type_select = select([widgetTypes.c.id]).where(
        widgetTypes.c.type==bindparam('type_name'))

insert = widgets.insert({'type': type_select})

conn.execute(insert, [
    {'name': 'Melon',  'type_name': 'Squidgy'},
    {'name': 'Lychee', 'type_name': 'Spiky'},
])
```

Comment: Fantastic that works a treat thanks. Saved me from having to make multiple round trips to the database - I can now do everything in a single query which saves a **lot** of time when your database is on the other side of the world.

Comment: What if `type_select` has two fields?